# Using LINQ on a List to return a subset list based on sequential dates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where I have a list of objects with a datetime field in the object.  I'm trying to find out if there is a way to use LINQ to group the list by sequential datetimes and return a subset of the list with the sequential datetimes as a range.

```
public virtual IList<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
...
public class LineItem
{
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime TransDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

So If I had 6 `LineItem`s with `Status = P` for all and

```
TransDate = { 8/1/2011 , 8/2/2011 , 8/3/2011 , 8/5/2011 , 8/6/2011 , 8/9/2011 }
```

respectively, I'd like to return the following list:

```
{ (P, 8/1/2011-8/3/2011) , (P,8/5/2011-8/6/2011) , (P,8/9/2011) }
```

Any thoughts?  I can do this with iterating through the list manually and checking the TransDate to see if it's sequential, I am just looking for a more elegant (preferably LINQ) way of doing it.  Thanks!

Comment: Will the dates be distinct? Also, are they guaranteed to be ordered chronologicially?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a helper method like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<ICollection<T>> PartitionByPredicate<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, T, bool> split)
{
    var buffer = new List<T>();

    foreach (var x in seq)
    {
        if (buffer.Any() && split(buffer.Last(), x))
        {
            yield return buffer;
            buffer = new List<T>();
        }

        buffer.Add(x);
    }

    if (buffer.Any())
        yield return buffer;
}
```

And then:

```
var sorted = LineItems.OrderBy(i => i.TransDate);
var split = sorted.PartitionByPredicate(
    (x, y) => (y.TransDate.Date - x.TransDate.Date).TotalDays > 1)
```

(edit: cleaned it up slightly, my first version was silly.)

Comment: I see, so you're putting in the ordered sequence and the `PartitionByPredicate` method starts the next partition when the predicate is true, which in this case is when there's a gap in the dates. +1 Very clever; nice, general, LINQy solution.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but, I thought I was reasonable at Linq, I read your answer, and I barely understood about 20% of it, which if only one thing shows how much I've still got to learn, Any pointers on books or useful articles to learn about some of the more advanced stuff in your answer such as yield and helper predicates?

Comment: I haven't read any C# books, but I can recommend as high quality Eric Lippert's blog or Bart de Smet's blog -- they often write long articles about C# language and LINQ stuff -- you may find them difficult but they are worth your time. I personally found that my experience with Scheme made it easy to pick up functional C# constructs, but this may be a very roundabout road to expertise.  For practice, I also recommend trying your hand at solving people's problems on Stack Overflow in your spare time :)

Comment: Thanks -- this led me in the right direction and worked great.  And I too ditto Chris' remark.  This really has been both humbling and eye-opening!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go with an iterator block implementation, as suggested by @mquander.

But here's a fun, pure LINQ solution that will work (albeit inefficiently), assuming the dates are distinct *and* chronological:

```
var groups = from item in LineItems
             let startDate = item.TransDate
             group item by LineItems.Select(lineItem => lineItem.TransDate)
                                    .SkipWhile(endDate => endDate < startDate)                                        
                                    .TakeWhile((endDate, index) => 
                                                startDate.AddDays(index) == endDate)
                                    .Last();

//If required:
 var groupsAsLists = groups.Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

This works by choosing the *last* sequential date in any date-sequence as the key for that sequence.

Comment: Hi Ani -- Thanks for the post, very interesting.  I ended up using the previous solution (as you suggested).  I had to add additional logic to the anonymous function (not necessarily unique dates), but still, many thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is very elegant, but its LINQ and it works :)

```
var list = new[] { 
    new DateTime(2011, 1, 1), 
    new DateTime(2011, 1, 2), 
    new DateTime(2011, 1, 3), 
    new DateTime(2011, 1, 5), 
    new DateTime(2011, 1, 6), 
    new DateTime(2011, 1, 8), 
    new DateTime(2011, 1, 10), 
};
var ordered = list.OrderBy(d => d);
var accum = ordered.Aggregate(new Dictionary<DateTime, List<DateTime>>(), (dic, val) => {
    if (!dic.Any())
    {
        dic.Add(val, new List<DateTime> { val });
    }
    else
    {
        if ((val - dic[dic.Keys.Last()].Last()).Days <= 1)
            dic[dic.Keys.Last()].Add(val);
        else
            dic.Add(val, new List<DateTime> { val });
    }
    return dic;
});
```

In result accum will have 4 groups: 1-3, 5-6, 8 and 10.

Comment: This won't work generally, since `dic.Values.Last()` may not actually be the last thing you put into the dictionary.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `dic.Keys.Last()` won't do any better.  Dictionaries are not ordered, by insertion sequence or any other externally obvious property.  They are hash tables, and there would be no way for them to also keep track of insertion order without either compromising their performance or using a lot of extra memory.